# highchart customize legend

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I will like to custom the legend of highchart, to achieve:

1. There will be dots instead of lines
2. The color of the dots and the color of the legend text will be equal to this.color
3. on invisible status (onclick legend) I will like to change the color to the default option of highchart (gray)

This is what I have so far:
[image]

what I did:

```
legend: {
    useHTML: true,
    symbolWidth: 0,
    lableFormat: '<div>' +
                    '<div style="border-radius:50%; width: 10px; height:10px: background-color:{color}; display: inline-block; margin-right:5px"> </div>' +
                    "<span style='color:{color};font-family:proximaNovaBold'> {name} </span>"
                 '<div>',
}
```

what I am missing:
- on click, the legend doesn't change his color to default gray color

I was looking for something like legend-labelFormat for invisible status, but I didn't find it in the docs of highchart (really good by the way), is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: Next time when you want to post a snippet of your code, please don't upload it as an image.

Comment: How about using `itemHiddenStyle` object property (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.itemHiddenStyle)? In case it will not help, provide us with a working example.

Comment: itemHiddenStyle doesnt work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer but it wasn’t easy as I hoped:

I used event listener plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick,
chart.legend.update, and legend.labelFormatter, with external variable

External Variable:

```
var legendsStatus = {};
```

Custom legend using labelFormatter:

```
legend :{
                        useHTML: true,
                        symbolWidth: 0,
                        labelFormatter: function () {
                                     return '<div>' +
                                                '<div style="border-radius: 50%; width: 10px; height: 10px; background-color: ' + this.color +'; display: inline-block; margin-right:5px"> </div>' +
                                                "<span style='color:" + this.color + "; font-family:proximaNovaBold'> " + this.name +  " </span>" +
                                            '</div>'
                                 }

                    },
```

Event listener using chart.legend.update:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        events : {
            legendItemClick : function(){

                legendsStatus[this.name] = this.visible;

                this.chart.legend.update( {
                    useHTML: true,
                    symbolWidth: 0,
                    labelFormatter: function () {

                                // legend status = visible
                                if (!legendsStatus[this.name])
                                     return '<div>' +
                                                '<div style="border-radius: 50%; width: 10px; height: 10px; background-color: ' + this.color +'; display: inline-block; margin-right:5px"> </div>' +
                                                "<span style='color:" + this.color + "; font-family:proximaNovaBold'> " + this.name +  " </span>" +
                                           '</div>'

                                // legend status = invisible
                                return '<div>' +
                                           '<div style="border-radius: 50%; width: 10px; height: 10px; background-color: #cccccc; display: inline-block; margin-right:5px"> </div>' +
                                           "<span style='color: #cccccc; font-family:proximaNovaBold'> " + this.name +  " </span>" +
                                      '</div>'
                             }
                });


            }
        }
    }
},
```